# Wrong data saved in file during writing in Android Development

Tags: android, file-io

I'm learning to write a demo about get input message from the EditText, but after finishing it, i found the message is wrong. I tried to log it. The answer is as below. 
Code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        String input = edit.toString();
        Log.i("tag",input);
        save(input);
    }

    public void save(String input){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try{
            out = openFileOutput("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
            writer.write(input);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if(writer != null){
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My log cat shows following response

[image]

Comment: you didn't get the text from the EditText, use: `edit.getText().toString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
String input = edit.toString();
```

with:

```
String input = edit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, solved. So if without the getText method, we'll get the unique identifier of the widget？

Comment: Method: findViewById
 finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
It returns: the view if found or null otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try

edit.getText().toString(); to get text from EditText

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use   `toString()` method it will give hashcode value of the object.
In your case it is giving hashcode value of `EditText` object you have created.

If you want to get the string value you have entered in EditText field u have to first get Editable from EditText example below

`editText.getText().toString()` it will return the value you have entered in `EditText`